# Spring Integration - Oracle lock contention

Tags: spring-integration

The jdbc inbound channel adapter and message stores in our application consistenly stops querying for data and I've been able to track it down to a blocked Oracle session.  In Oracle, we are getting enq: TX - row lock contention.  The DBA tracked it down to the following:

```
SELECT COMPLETE, LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE
from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP
where GROUP_KEY = :1 and REGION=:2
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

SI configuration (extract):

```
<int-jdbc:message-store id="jdbc-messageStore" data-source="dataSource"  /> 
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="JDBCInboundChannel"     query="${cache.integration.jdbc.selectQuery}" 
    channel="inboundMessagesChannel" data-source="dataSource"  update="update CACHE_REPOSITORY set STATUS='P' WHERE GUID IN (:guid)" row-mapper="rowMapper" 
    max-rows-per-poll="${cache.integration.jdbc.maxRowsPerPoll}" auto-startup="false" >
    <int:poller id="jdbcPoller" fixed-delay="${cache.integration.jdbc.fixedDelay}"   >
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:chain...>
<int:aggregator id="reportTypeAggregator" ref="aggregatorBean" method="collect"
         message-store="jdbc-messageStore" release-strategy="releaseStrategry"  
        release-strategy-method="canRelease" correlation-strategy="reportTypeCorrelationStrategry"
        correlation-strategy-method="correlate" send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
        expire-groups-upon-completion="true" empty-group-min-timeout="30000" />
</int:chain>        
<bean id="queryProvider" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider"/>     
 <bean id="jdbc-channel-messageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>   
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="queryProvider"/>
    <property name="region" value="${cache.integration.channelMessageStore.region}"/>

</bean>     

<int:channel id="archiveCreationChannel" >  
    <int:queue  message-store="jdbc-channel-messageStore" />
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger" timeout="-1"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<bean id="documentMessageStoreReaper" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="jdbc-messageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="${cache.integration.reaper.timeout}" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="documentMessageStoreReaper" method="run" fixed-rate="10000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Comment: The select that you have shown can not cause this wait event. A row lock contention happens when two sessions update the same row or do a `select ... FOR UPDATE` for the same row. But a plain `select` will not cause this.

Comment: That was the query provided by my DBA as what he found related to the lock.  I have another tool an extremely long query on the same table.    DELETE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY=:1 and REGION=:2

Comment: You can check also this one in the moment when the contention will be happening.. https://www.crealoq.com/solved/Identify-Blocking-Session-Blocked-Session-Blocked-Statement-and-Locked-Objects-in-Oracle-DB

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the main issue is around `fixed-rate` for `documentMessageStoreReaper`, which initiate the `DELETE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP`. You should change it to the `fixed-dealy` to avoid concurrent tasks.

Since you say that the `DELETE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP` is very long, hence 10 sec between tasks might be not enough.